# What can I eat while walking?

Tags: walking

I usually go out in the evening for walking to get some physical workout done as I have a sedentary lifestyle (I sit a lot in workplace as I am a computer programmer). I walk for nearly 30-40 mins or sometimes for almost 1 hr and I go for walking at around 7 pm. While walking I feel the urge to eat and drink something. Is it good to eat or drink while walking? If yes then what is the best food or fruits or supplements that I can carry along with me while walking?

Comment: What is the length and timing (total time taken & part of the day) of your walk? Edit and add these to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want, take some water with you. Its not bad to eat or drink while walking, but food for a short walk is completely unnecessary.

If its a short slow walk you don't *need* to eat. And if you are a sedentary office worker, you probably meet your caloric requirements. Take a few sips to hydrate your mouth, and you'll probably notice your "hunger" disappear.